# Node.js, MYSQL - how to get ONLY the data without column name

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm using a select statement to pull the data from a mysql server:

```
client.query('SELECT attend FROM testnumbers WHERE Gym =2', function(err,result){
        var jay = result;
        console.log(jay);
});
```

When it returns 'jay', the result is this:

```
[ { attend: 455 } ]
```

I want ONLY the number to be in the variable 'jay'. How can I get rid of the other query stuff? Thanks!

Comment: var jay = result[attend]; maybe I'm not sure

Comment: Sorry, it says 'attend is not defined' :/

Comment: var jay = result.attend; maybe

Comment: Sorry again...now 'jay' appears to be undefined. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: I think it would actually be result[0].attend

Comment: @pj409, you might want to check basic javascript on arrays. It will help you a lot and save you hours of debugging while you are learning this language.

Answer (score 0):

What is being returned is called javascript object notation, or JSON. You must parse it. Many ways to extract that data:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Plus tons of other tuts on parsing JSON with js.